# For a square matrix, row vectors are linearly independent if and only if columns are.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way of proving this from ground up? namely using brute force computation entries by entries to show this?

Comment: Hint: row rank = column rank and if all columns are linearly independent, then column rank = $n$ for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you mean with "from ground up"

If the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, then doing row-reduction to $A$ gives the dentity matrix, so the only solution of $Av=0$ is $v=0$.

If the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent, say, $$a_1c_1+a_2c_2+\cdots+a_nc_n=0$$ where the $c_i$ are the columns and the $a_i$ are not all zero, then $Av=0$ where $$v=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\ne0$$

So, if the columns are dependent, then so are the rows.

Now apply the same argument to $A^T$ to conclude that if the rows of $A$ are dependent then so are the columns.

Comment: I guess I would like to be convinced of your first statement, why do row vectors being linearly independent implies v is the only solution to Av = 0 via row reduction?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be a field.
$\renewcommand\Im{\operatorname{Im}}$
Consider a $n\times m$-matrix as a $K$-linear mapping $\varphi:K^m\to K^n$.
The column rank is the dimension $\dim_K(\Im\varphi)$, while the row rank is the dimension $\dim_K(\Im\varphi^\ast)$ of the transpose $\varphi^\ast$ of $\varphi$.
Recall that we have a $K$-linear isomorphism
\begin{align}
&(\Im\varphi)^\ast\xrightarrow\sim\Im\varphi^\ast&
&\lambda\mapsto\lambda\circ\varphi
\end{align}
which implies
\begin{align*}
\dim(\Im\varphi)&=\dim(\Im\varphi)^\ast\\
&=\dim(\Im\varphi^\ast)
\end{align*}
thus proving our assertion.