# Intuition: If the columns of a matrix are colinear, then its rows are also colinear.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

For simplicity's sake, I'm working with a 3x3 square matrix in which none of the column or row vectors is the zero vector.

I tried graphing the columns of the matrix {{1,4,-3},{2,7,-5},{3,6,-3}} (where each group of $3$ is a row) and those $3$ vectors are on the same plane. I understand why that's the case; what I don't understand is why it necessarily implies that the $3$ row vectors are also on a single plane.

I have some algebraic intuition for the 2d case. For example with vectors v = <1,2> and w = <3,6>, the fact that w = 3v means that the respective components of the two vectors are in the same proportion, and therefore the vectors x = <1,3> and y = <2,6> are also colinear.

I tried to extend that kind of logic to the 3d case but I didn't manage to because of the increased complexity. For ex in the 3x3 matrix that I used, if column vectors are u, v and w, then u = v + w. Since one vector isn't simply a scalar multiple of another as in the 2d case, I can't seem to apply the same logic of proportions kept.

I saw this question: [For a square matrix, row vectors are linearly independent if and only if columns are.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782047/for-a-square-matrix-row-vectors-are-linearly-independent-if-and-only-if-columns), but it doesn't give the kind of intuition I'm looking for.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rows are coplanar, then there exists a nonzero linear combination $x_1R_1+x_2R_2+x_3R_3=0$ with at least one of $x_1,x_2,x_3\ne 0$. But this says that $LM=0$, where $L$ is the row vector $L=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $M$ is the matrix with rows $R_1,R_2,R_3$. Then $Me_i$ is the $i$th column, $C_i$, of the matrix where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector, so $LMe_i=0$ for all $i$. Hence $LC_i=0$ for all $i$. Thus all the columns of $M$ lie in the plane $x_1x+x_2y+x_3z=0$.

I've added [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989426/90543) with a more general explanation of how this works to [the question Will Jagy linked in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332908/90543), though I'm not sure if the general case will be useful to you or not.

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of insight I was looking for. Took me a while to fully integrate but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not true that if rows are colinear then columns are collinear.

For example a $3\times 2$ matrix with rows $(1,2),(2,1)(3,3)$ has dependent rows but independent columns.

What is true is the row rank is the same as column rank .

Comment: But the result is true in the square case.

Comment: Yes the result is true for square matrices.

Comment: I don't want to downvote because you took the time to answer, but this doesn't answer my question at all, and I specify in my post that I'm talking about a 3x3 square matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was mislead by the title in assuming the general case .